# How to convert ajax in javascript to UrlFetchApp in Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, unauthorized

I'd like to get data from szimek ad suite api in google script.
Here is example to get data from szimek api in javascript.

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://adapi.uat.sizmek.com/sas/login/login",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "api-key": "api key token",
        "": ""
    },
    "data": "{username:\"Username\", password: \"Password\"}",
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

[Szimek api Help](https://developers.sizmek.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029612011-Authentication)

so I converted code in google script.

```
const API_KEY = '[api token]';
var url = 'https://adapi.sizmek.com/sas/login/login/'

// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
  'username': '[username]',
  'password': '[password]',
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  "headers":{
            Authorization: API_KEY
  },
  "payload": JSON.stringify(data),
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

But I got unauthorized error. what is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot test your request, if your top script is correct, I thought that `Authorization: API_KEY` might be `"api-key": "api key token",`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
"headers":{
          Authorization: API_KEY
},
```

#### To:

```
"headers":{ "api-key": "api key token" },
```

#### Note:

- I'm worried that when `"": ""` is included in the request header, an error might occur.
- When I saw your top script again, each key of `"{username:\"Username\", password: \"Password\"}"` is not enclosed by `"`. I think that if this is correct, I think that `"{username:\"Username\", password: \"Password\"}"` might not be able to be parsed as a JSON object. But, I'm not sure about the specification of the server side. So, if the above modification was not the direct solution to your issue, please test the following modification.

  - From

    ```
      "headers":{
                Authorization: API_KEY
      },
      "payload": JSON.stringify(data),
    ```
  - To

    ```
      "headers":{ "api-key": "api key token" },
      "payload": "{username:\"Username\", password: \"Password\"}",
    ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, right!
I'd like to show data in data studio. how should I do?

Comment: @Bohdan V. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I'd like to show data in data studio. how should I do?`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?